# Style python qrcode SVG image

Tags: python, svg, qr-code

I use the python module "qrcode" to create vCard QR codes:

https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode

It works, but i want to create the QR code images in SVG format *and* style them, for example by defining the color of the QR code.

Having tried around with `.png` format, the linked documentation is enough information to get this done.

Now, using `.svg`, i can create working codes, but only black code on white background - and i can't make use of the information in the docs to specify the color.

Here's the QR code generation i use *(shortened)*:

```
import qrcode
import qrcode.image.svg

vcard_data = """BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
...etc...
END:VCARD"""

factory = qrcode.image.svg.SvgPathImage
img = qrcode.make(vcard_data, image_factory=factory)

img.save(output_image) # full path and name of the .svg defined before
```

When using `.png`, i could modify colors using

```
img = qr.make_image(fill_color=(12, 73, 114), back_color=(255, 255, 255))
```

...but the whole PNG image creation uses `.make_image`, while the SVG is created using `.make` and that doesn't take arguments like this.

How can i adjust the color settings of the resulting SVG?

**Update:**

I tried to generate an SVG using `.make_image` but i can't make that work. All styling options seem to rely on `StylerdPilImage` but that seems like it only supports *.png*.

If i understand the docs correctly, an `image_factory` and a `module_drawer` and a `color_mask` should work, but as far as i can tell not for SVG.

This is what i've tried now, but it does not work:

```
import qrcode
import qrcode.image.svg
from qrcode.image.styledpil import StyledPilImage
from qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers.svg import SvgSquareDrawer
from qrcode.image.styles.colormasks import SolidFillColorMask
    
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version=None,
    error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_M,
    box_size=4,
    border=0,
    image_factory=StyledPilImage
)

qr.add_data(vcard_data)

img = qr.make_image(
    module_drawer=SvgSquareDrawer(), 
    color_mask=SolidFillColorMask(
        front_color=(12, 73, 114),
        back_color=(255, 255, 255)
    )
)

img.save(output_image)
```

That leads to:

> AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'Resampling'

I begin to think no one uses the "qrcode" module to generate styled SVGs. It seems like this *could* be done somehow, but... not really?

Comment: Have you tried using `.make_image()` with SVG?  As far as I can tell `.make()` is just a shortcut for calling `.make_image()` with no parameters.

Comment: @jasonharper: Thanks for your comment! I tried `.make_image`, but just changing this didn't work. I tried to understand the docs and came up with another approach, see my edited question - it doesn't work. Honestly, the docs are really not clear on how to get things done using this module. It seems like there are options that can be used to get what i want - but... how? Any other python qr code module tipps?

Comment: You can use [`qrcode-artistic`](https://segno.readthedocs.io/en/stable/artistic-qrcodes.html), it can converts a (Micro) QR Code to a Pillow Image or into a QR code with a background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution right now, as i can't find a way to specify the color on creation of the *.svg*:

I read the generatet image file, change the values and save it again. Not the most elegant way, but working.

```
with open(output_image, "r") as qr_img:
    content = qr_img.read()

content = content.replace("#000000", qr_color) # a hex color string like "#FF0000"

with open(output_image, "w+") as qr_img:
    qr_img.write(content)
```